# Avatar WordPress and WooCommerce

Tags: avatar

I have given permission to the user to choose an avatar by using a plugin
But the problem is that when the avatar is uploaded, it is only displayed on WooCommerce pages, and the default WordPress avatar is displayed in the main parts of WordPress, such as the home page or posts.
How to integrate WooCommerce and WordPress avatars?

How to integrate WooCommerce and WordPress avatars?Avatar